# SRTM elevation data download error QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, error, srtm

I am trying to download SRTM rester data in QGIS for a specific area. See image below:

[image: Canvas extent]
I am using SRTM-Downloader plugin and when I click on download the following error pops up. Any idea about what the problem is?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3):

There's no SRTM data available above 60°N.  See below screenshot of the [SRTM product coverage map from USGS](https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/ee-data/coveragemaps/shp/ee/srtm/srtm.zip).

[image]

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to look at downloading ASTER Global DEM (GDEM) V3 data, its coverage spans from 83°N to 83°S. It's available from https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/